# Can we send back data from App to Chrome in previous opened Tab?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, callback, android-browser

I have made a payment app in Java Kotlin. My requirement is that a webpage can call my app for payment then after successful payment I can response back that webpage with transaction ID.

From web page, I have called app through Android's Intend feature and made payment successfully. while reverting back to chrome I am facing issue.

**If I use HTTP URL intend then it opens new Tab everytime**,

```
 dataUri = Uri.parse("https://URL.com/app.php?amount=2&t_Id=123123123");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, dataUri);
```

**Another option is to target chrome through Intend again.**

```
 dataUri = Uri.parse("//googlechrome:");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, dataUri);
```

It is working but issue I am getting in this is not able to send data. I understand that with intend we are just changing focus back to chrome. I tried Put extra paramteres but it didn't work.

```
    intent.putExtra("t_Id", "12345");
```

Can any one suggest a better solution for it?

Comment: What about focusing on the user session the the website rather than a tab? If the payment is made and your app can just return success data to the website with everything related to the user that made de payment

Comment: Yes,  @esQmo_ if extra parameteres worked then I can pass session ID too.